# Slow postgresql query if where clause matches no rows

Tags: postgresql

I have a simple table in a PostgreSQL 9.0.3 database that holds data polled from a wind turbine controller.  Each row represents the value of a particular sensor at a particular time.  Currently the table has around 90M rows:

```
wtdata=> \d integer_data
          Table "public.integer_data"
 Column |           Type           | Modifiers 
--------+--------------------------+-----------
 date   | timestamp with time zone | not null
 name   | character varying(64)    | not null
 value  | integer                  | not null
Indexes:
    "integer_data_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (date, name)
    "integer_data_date_idx" btree (date)
    "integer_data_name_idx" btree (name)
```

One query that I need is to find the last time that a variable was updated:

```
select max(date) from integer_data where name = '<name of variable>';
```

This query works fine when searching for a variable that exists in the table:

```
wtdata=> select max(date) from integer_data where name = 'STATUS_OF_OUTPUTS_UINT16';
          max           
------------------------
 2011-04-11 02:01:40-05
(1 row)
```

However, if I try and search for a variable that doesn't exist in the table, the query hangs (or takes longer than I have patience for):

```
select max(date) from integer_data where name = 'Message';
```

I've let the query run for hours and sometimes days with no end in sight.  There are no rows in the table with name = 'Message':

```
wtdata=> select count(*) from integer_data where name = 'Message';
 count 
-------
     0
(1 row)
```

I don't understand why one query is fast and the other takes forever.  Is the query somehow being forced to scan the entire table for some reason?

```
wtdata=> explain select max(date) from integer_data where name = 'Message';
                                                       QUERY PLAN                                                       
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Result  (cost=13.67..13.68 rows=1 width=0)
   InitPlan 1 (returns $0)
     ->  Limit  (cost=0.00..13.67 rows=1 width=8)
           ->  Index Scan Backward using integer_data_pkey on integer_data  (cost=0.00..6362849.53 rows=465452 width=8)
                 Index Cond: ((date IS NOT NULL) AND ((name)::text = 'Message'::text))
(5 rows)
```

Here's the query plan for a fast query:

```
wtdata=> explain select max(date) from integer_data where name = 'STATUS_OF_OUTPUTS_UINT16';
                                                        QUERY PLAN                                                        
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Result  (cost=4.64..4.65 rows=1 width=0)
   InitPlan 1 (returns $0)
     ->  Limit  (cost=0.00..4.64 rows=1 width=8)
           ->  Index Scan Backward using integer_data_pkey on integer_data  (cost=0.00..16988170.38 rows=3659570 width=8)
                 Index Cond: ((date IS NOT NULL) AND ((name)::text = 'STATUS_OF_OUTPUTS_UINT16'::text))
(5 rows)
```

Comment: Have you ran analyze on this table?

Comment: Yes, I've run analyze manually, plus autovacuum is running.

Comment: Any chance you can share your database in a compressed file?  Looks like a good learning opportunity?

Comment: I'd be willing to share it with a few people as there's nothing really "private" but I'd rather not link to the data in a public forum.  Is there a way I could send you the link out of band?

Comment: You'll get a bit more info if you use `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` instead of `EXPLAIN`.  `EXPLAIN` just returns the query plan.  `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` actually runs the query, and then returns the query plan with real-world timing info.

Comment: Does this behave any differently?: `SELECT date FROM from integer_data where name = 'Message' ORDER BY DATE DESC LIMIT 1;`

Comment: @Frank - No the query you posted takes forever as well.

Comment: Is there a reason you prefer the primary key to be (date,name) rather than (name,date). To me the latter would seem more natural.

Comment: @Gavin - no there's no reason to have the primary key specified as (date, name) vs (name, date), at least none that I know of.

Comment: @Gavin - I'm building an index on (name, date) now but it'll be a while before it's finished.

Comment: @Gavin - Yay! now that I have the (name, date) index my query is fast!  If you want to add an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Shouldn't string comparisions always be made with `LIKE` instead of `=`? `SELECT MAX(date) FROM integer_data WHERE name LIKE 'Message';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the primary key to (name,date).