# Postgresql select command slow if record doesn't exist

Tags: python, psycopg2, postgresql-9.2

I have the following select command. The tables has about 2million records. The record I'm looking for doesn't exist. But the select query is slow. How do I speed this up? Others have had this problem, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623353/slow-postgresql-query-if-where-clause-matches-no-rows), but the solution in that case doesn't apply.

```
a1_value = 'AA'
a2_value = "1"
cur.execute("SELECT pk, a1, a2 FROM db_name WHERE a1 = %s AND a2 = %s LIMIT 1", (a1_value, a2_value))
```

Comment: put indexes on a1 and a2

Comment: Sorry, I am new to this. What do you mean? Can you give a code example?

Comment: I have not worked with postgresql but you have to create indexes on the columns you are using in where clause. That will speed things up *significantly* [documenation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createindex.html)

Comment: Make sure you check the examples at the bottom of the link above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is put indices on a1 and a2. For example:
    cur.execute("CREATE INDEX index_title ON db_name (a1, a2)")
    cur.execute("SELECT pk, a1, a2 FROM db_name WHERE a1 = %s AND a2 = %s LIMIT 1", (a1_value, a2_value))